# if statement does not work inside while loop which is inside for loop

Tags: php, if-statement, for-loop, while-loop

I've already spent hours over this problem , and searched for answer online, but found nothing that helped me.

So, I am making a filter for a hotel website, and one of the criteria for hotel search is the district where the hotel is located. I use GET method:

```
<?php if (isset($_GET['District1'])){
    $district1= ($_GET["District1"]);
    }else ($district1=0);
if (isset($_GET['District2'])){
    $district2= ($_GET["District2"]);
    }else ($district2=0);
if (isset($_GET['District3'])){
    $district3= ($_GET["District3"]);
    }else ($district3=0);
if (isset($_GET['District4'])){
    $district4= ($_GET["District4"]);
    }else ($district4=0);
?>
```

where $district1, $district2, $district3, $district4 are 4 different districts of the city.

What I am trying to do is to build the district variables by using **for loop** (the digit at the end of variable name would be ascending by 1 : $district1..**2**..**3**..**4**),

then place these district variables in an **if clause** which is inside **while loop** as follows:

```
<?php 
$districts_filter_query="SELECT * FROM districts_table ";
        $districts_filter_result = mysql_query($districts_filter_query, $connect);
        $districts_filter_row = mysql_fetch_array($districts_filter_result);
        for($count = 1; $count <= 4 ; $count++){

do {

        $district_name = $districts_filter_row['district_name'];
        $district_value = $districts_filter_row['district_value'];



    echo '
           <label for="group13"> <p ';  ?> <?php 
            if ( eval(' return $district'.$count.';') !=0){echo 'class="greenBG"';}
                    else {echo ' class="checkbox" ';}?> <?php echo ' >
                    <input type="checkbox" name="District'.$count.'" id="group13" value="'.$district_value.'"
                         onClick="this.form.submit();" ';?> 
                    <?php if ( eval (' return $district'.$count.';') !=0){echo ' checked ';};?><?php echo '/> '.$district_name.' 
                </p>
           </label> ';

    }
    while($districts_filter_row = mysql_fetch_array ($districts_filter_result));
    }
?>
```

The problem is here, I guess: eval(' return $district'.$count.';'), by this I try to construct district variable names. But it does not work.

Everything works perfectly if I use this code:

```
            <label for="group1"> <p <?php 
            if ($district1!=0){echo 'class="greenBG"';}
                    else echo 'class="checkbox"';?>>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="District1" id="group1" value='1013' onClick="this.form.submit();" 
                    <?php if ($district1!=0){echo 'checked ';};?>/> district1
                </p>
           </label>
            <label for="group2"> <p <?php 
             if ($district2!=0){echo   'class="greenBG"';}
                    else echo 'class="checkbox"';?>>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="District2" id="group2" value='1014' onClick="this.form.submit();" 
                    <?php if ($district2!=0){echo 'checked ';};?>/> district2
                </p>
           </label>
            <label for="group3"> <p <?php 
            if ($district3!=0){echo 'class="greenBG"';}
                    else echo 'class="checkbox"';?>>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="District3" id="group3" value='1015' onClick="this.form.submit();" 
                    <?php if ($district3!=0){echo 'checked ';};?>/> district3
                </p>
           </label>
             <label for="group4"> <p <?php 
            if ($district4!=0){echo 'class="greenBG"';}
                    else echo 'class="checkbox"';?>>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="District4" id="group4" value='1016' onClick="this.form.submit();" 
                    <?php if ($district4!=0){echo 'checked ';};?>/>  district4
                </p>
           </label>
```

But this is not suitable for me because there are more than 30 districts, and it would take a lot of time and effort to make any minor change to code.

I would be greatful if you help me solve this problem and save my time. Thanks, hope my question is clear enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php instead of some ugly `eval()`. (For example `${"district$count"}`)

```
$count = 0;
do {
    $count++;
    $district_name = $districts_filter_row['district_name'];
    $district_value = $districts_filter_row['district_value'];
?>
<label for="group<?php echo $count; ?>">
    <p <?php 
        if (${"district$count"} != 0) echo 'class="greenBG"';
        else echo 'class="checkbox"'; ?>>
        <input type="checkbox" name="District<?php echo $count; ?>" id="group<?php echo $count; ?>" value='<?php echo $district_value; ?>' onClick="this.form.submit();" 
        <?php if (${"district$count"} != 0) echo 'checked '; ?>/> <?php echo $district_name; ?>
    </p>
</label>
<?php
}
while($districts_filter_row = mysql_fetch_array ($districts_filter_result));
```

And then delete this for loop around it.

Answer (score 0):

that's a little convoluted as an approach, but a quick solution to get rid of `eval` is to use variable variables:

```
<?php
$district_name = "district$count";
if ($$district_name != 0) { ... }
?>
```

... though a better solution would be to just use an array and loop through it.